# Passing custom size multidimensional array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array with known `x` size (5) and the `y` is taken from variable, so the array is something like this - `array[5][y];`

And now I'm quite troubled how to pass it to function, I won't edit it, just read the data from it.

I thought to do something like this:

```
void someFunction(double **array)
```

but I get

```
convert error: cannot convert `double (*)[((unsigned int)((int)n))]' to `double**' for argument `2' to `void findMax(int, double**, int)'|
```

Comment: Please post the code you are having trouble with. Post the function definition and your calling code.

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Array [5][x]**

Unfortunately you cannot define a type for an array like `double[5][]`. You can only omit the first dimension of a multidimensional array, not the last.

**For Array [x][5]**

You should go with `void someFunction(double array[][5], int size)`.
And then you loop trough the elements with `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`.

Example:

```
void someFunction(double array[][5], int size) {
    for (int k = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            std::cout << array[k][i] << std::endl;
}


double a[10][5];
// populate data
someFunction(a, 10);
```

Usually it's preferred to use `std::` containers instead of raw C arrays.

Take a look at [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for example.

Comment: I know about vectors, but the thing is that teachers wants me to do some excercises with arrays, because according to her std is for "lazy people" ^^

Comment: @EdgarasAusvicas, I've been there aswell. I know what you are talking about.

Comment: by the way now im getting this:
declaration of `array' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

Comment: @EdgarasAusvicas your teacher should not be allowed to teach C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the STL, you can also do this:

```
void someFunction(double **mat, const int Xsize, const int Ysize )
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < Xsize ; ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < Ysize ; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << ((double *)mat + Ysize * i)[j] << "  " ;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return ;
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double matrice[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    someFunction( (double**)matrice, 2, 3 );
    return 1;
}
```